# Using list.files() how can I get file names that start with a pattern, not that simply contain the pattern?

Tags: r, data-management

I am using list.files() to list the files in a directory. However, many of the files contain similar strings, but are in a different group.

```
write.csv(mtcars, "test1.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "test2.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "another_test1.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "another_test2.csv")

### list files 
pattern_text <- c("test")
list.files(pattern = pattern_text)

[1]  "another_test1.csv" "another_test2.csv"         
[3]        "test1.csv"         "test2.csv"
```

But I'd like it to grab the files whose names START with "test" not just simply contain "test" in the name. If I use the code as it is, I get all the file names with "test" in it.

I want to end up with only test1.csv and test2.csv

Comment: pattern = "^test"

Answer (score 2):

if you want only the files that start with "test", you can use regular expressions (regex) inside of the `pattern=` argument of `list_files()`. If you want to learn more about regex, you can call `?regex` in the R console. In this case, adding the metacharacter `^` (a caret) to your code gets the desired result.

```
write.csv(mtcars, "test1.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "test2.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "another_test1.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "another_test2.csv")

### list files 
list.files(pattern = "^test")
[1] "test1.csv" "test2.csv"
```

In this case, the `^` symbol is a meta-character that matches the empty string at the *beginning* of a line. That way, only file names that have nothing before "test" will show up (e.g., "testing" would show up but "attest" would not).

Comment: This would work well but how do I use the regular expression with a variable name?

list.files(pattern = "^[VARIABLE NAME]")

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question - if you had a variable named "my_variable", for instance, you would pass `pattern="^my_variable"` to the `list.files()` function. Also, the square brackets `[ ]` have significance in regex in that they signal a *character class*. This is a list of different characters which looks for a match to *any* character in the list. So if you had `pattern=[abc]` for instance, R would look for any file name that contains 'a', 'b', or 'c'. Unless you plan to use a regular expression inside a function besides `list.files()`?

Comment: Putting the "^variable_name" does not work since R sees that as a string. 

I have a dynamic name. I am running this in a loop so I have to be able to account or a series of names.

Comment: Try `paste0("^", my_variable)`